# Do lock objects in Java need to be static?

Tags: java, multithreading

I know in C# when you have an object you want to use as a lock for multi-threading, you should declare it as static inside of a class, which the class instance will be running in a separate thread.

Does this hold true for Java as well? Some examples online seem to declare the lock object as only final...

Edit:
I have a resource that I want to limit to only one thread access at a time. A class that extends Thread will be used to create multiple instances and started at the same time. What should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually if you want to lock the whole class you can just do that: synchronized(MyClass.class){...}  You don't need a static lock object.  Unless you have multiple resources.  ALSO you can use java.util.concurrent.locks.* which have a lot of useful lock types with more flexability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on in which context they are to be used. If you want a per-instance lock, then leave `static` away. If you want a per-class lock, then use `static`. Further indeed keep it `final`.

Comment: Thanks, owe you another one :-P

Comment: If you want a per-class lock, then you are probably doing something wrong (it can be useful for the likes of caches, but generally mutable statics are bad).

Comment: I have a resource that I want to limit to only one thread access at a time. A class that extends Thread will be used to create multiple instances and started at the same time. What should I use?

Comment: Then use a per-class (`static`) lock, or consider using a `synchronized` method for the particular puspose.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer, no. Long answer, it depends on what you want.

```
private static final Object STATIC_LOCK = new Object();

private final Object lock = new Object();

public void doSomething() {
    synchronized (STATIC_LOCK) {
        // At most, one thread can enter this portion
    }

    synchronized (lock) {
        // Many threads can be here at once, but only one per object of the class
    }
}
```

With that being said, I would recommend you look at the locks provided in [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html). Using [`java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) you can do the following:

```
Lock l = ...;
l.lock();
try {
    // access the resource protected by this lock
} finally {
    l.unlock();
}
```

Comment: That clarifies even more. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No

In Java it is possible to use non-static members as locks.

```
private Object lock = new Object();

public void test(){
    synchronized (lock) {
      // your code  
    }
}
```

Comment: As IntelliJ likes to tell me "Synchronization on a non-final field is unlikely to have useful semantics."